# Find the directional derivative of $f(x,y) = x^2 e^{xy}$ at (-1,0) in the direction of a unit vector that makes an angle A with a positive x-axis.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I do not understand what I am require to find in the above equation. I know that u = (cosA, sinA) = cosAi + sinAi, ||u|| = 1

Comment: You're required to find the directional derivative of $f(x, y) = x^2 e^{xy}$ in the direction of a unit vector that makes a (given?) angle with the positive $x$-axis. To start with, do you understand the terms in the question? Do you know how to compute a directional derivative?

Comment: Partial of it. I do not understand it fully

Comment: What exactly don't you understand?

Comment: I do not understand the vector part of the formula of the direction derivative. I do understand the gradient part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directional derivative of a function $f$ in the direction of a unit vector $\hat u$ is given by

$$\frac{df}{du}=\nabla f\cdot \hat u$$

Let the unit vector $\hat u$ be such that $\hat u \cdot \hat x =\cos(\theta)$ and the function $f$ be given by $f(x,y)=x^2e^{xy}$.  Then, we have

$$\nabla f(x,y)=\hat x\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}+\hat y\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=\left(\hat x (2x+x^2y)+\hat y x^3\right)e^{xy}$$

At the point $(-1,0)$ the gradient is

$$\left.\nabla f(x,y)\right|_{(-1,0)}=-(2\hat x+\hat y)$$

and the directional derivative is

$$\frac{df}{du}=-(2\cos(\theta)+\sin(\theta))$$